# Saving a batch variable in a text file

Tags: variables, batch-file, save, io-redirection

I am trying to save a batch variable into a text file. I currently have this code:

```
@echo off

Set var=6
@echo %var%>txt.txt

For /f "tokens*" %%i in (txt.txt) do @echo %%i
Pause
```

It's supposed to save the 6 into the variable var and then write the variable in a text file. I want to do this to save user input into a text file so that when the batch program is terminated it will hold the variables.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a little problem with redirection. You are redirecting a "stream"; they are numbered 0-9. 0 is for "Standard Input" (STDIN), 1 is for "Standard Output" (STDOUT), 2 is for "Error Output" (STDERR).

If you use the redirection symbol `>` without a stream number, it defaults to "1".

So `echo text>txt.txt` is just an abreviation for `echo text 1>txt.txt`

Now it's getting tricky: `echo 6>txt.txt` won't echo "6" to the file, but tries to redirect "Stream 6" (which is empty) to the file. The Standard Output `echo is off` goes to the screen, because "Stream1" is not redirected.

Solution:

If you try to redirect a number or a string which ends with a number, just use a different syntax:

```
>txt.txt echo 6
```

Comment: Alternative: `echo 6 1> txt.txt`, or `@echo %var% 1>txt.txt` in the original example. Alternative way to verify the output: `type txt.txt`.

Comment: @Johan: both alternatives will write an additional space to the file (which is unnecessary and a potential trouble maker). "Real" alternatives are `(echo 6)>txt.txt` or `(echo %var%)>txt.txt

Answer (score 4):

Use the set command to get the contents of a file:

```
set /p var=<filename
```

Use the echo command to put into a file:

```
@echo Contents Of File > "FileName"
```

To append another line to the end of the file, use:

```
@echo Contents Of File >> "FileName"
```

Also, put the commands on separate lines or use '&&' between them on the same line.

Comment: I use @echo %var%>txt.txt and i just get the batch file saying echo is off

Comment: use: >txt.txt echo %var%