# >nul redirection before or after command in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, nul

In command prompt, the following two lines give the same output, I want to know the usage difference between them. Thanks.

`>nul dir`

`dir >nul`

Comment: theoretically both syntaxes are interchangable. Theoretically... For [certain reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28260620/2152082) the first is safer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference, they redirect the same amount of output. You can combine the input and output redirection operators in multiple ways: `> out.txt command < in.txt` or `< in.txt command > out.txt`.

As noted in the comments, you have to be careful if something contains the number 1 or 2, you don't want `%something%>out.txt` to expand to `...2>out.txt` and you can do that with a space or by putting it before the rest of the command.

Comment: it's not only 1 or 2, it's 0 to 9